# How to add <br/> tag in React in this situation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add br tag in this situation?

```
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      {`aaaa <br />bbbb`}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a literal string.

```
<main>
  aaaa <br/>bbbb
</main>
```

If you must use a HTML string, you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but know that this is generally not recommended.

```
<main dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'aaaa <br />bbbb'}}/>
```

Comment: This code is just for example here.  I have to use literal string in real project. So, the question is, how?

Comment: @FuadRustamzade You could use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but it's not a good idea: `<main dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'aaaa <br />bbbb'}}/>`

Comment: try<div></div> an empty div

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

For general use cases, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` should be fine. Beware that setting HTML from public text/strings is a major risk due to XSS attack.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'aaaa <br />bbbb'}} />
```

### Option 2: [`html-react-parser`](https://npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)

You may also try this library in place of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. You may do something like this -

```
import parse from "html-react-parser";
parse("<main>aaaa <br />bbbb</main>")
```